# ThreeJS - Getting the "existing" color in a FragmentShader

Tags: three.js

A bit new to ThreeJS. I have a bunch of instanced meshes and doing setColorAt's for each of them. I have their materials set to a ShaderMaterial with a vertexShader and fragmentShader.

I want to experiment with writing vertex shaders but keep the existing colors that I have for the meshes.
My fragment shader:

```
        void main() {

            gl_FragColor = /* How do I get the "existing" or whatever the color used to be?

        }
```

From my understanding, the "existing" color isn't available during this part of the rendering pipeline, so there isn't really a way to do something like gl_FragColor=gl_FragColor or anything of the sort.

From what I was reading from other posts, the only way to retrieve the existing colors that they were set with is to render them once with a regular MeshStandardMaterial, write that render to a texture, and then create a composer pass and pass in the texture to that passes fragmentShader.

Are there any good & simple examples of this technique being used? I have a specific algorithm that is setting the colors of each of the meshes, so I want to be able to keep those while modifying the vertices. Also, if there is a way to simply ignore the fragmentShader and only use a vertexShader I would be OK with that too as long as I could still customize the color for each mesh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured it out.

`instanceColor` is available to the vertexShader. So just make a `varying vec3` to store it and pass to the fragmentShader.

Answer (score 1):

Instances can only be customized via geometry attributes (which can be split up per-vertex/instance), whereas uniforms are global and will apply to every vertex/instance of a mesh (instancing is just drawing a single mesh multiple times, so you'd interface with it as a single mesh).

[`InstancedMesh.setColorAt`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/objects/InstancedMesh.setColorAt) will set a per "instance" color via geometry attributes, similar to how you would with vertex colors. In threejs, you can access this via `instanceColor` in your vertex shader or [`InstancedMesh.instanceColor`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/objects/InstancedMesh.instanceColor) via three.

[Some more reading on WebGLPrograms and built-ins](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/webgl/WebGLProgram).

Comment: setColorAt sets the per instance color, but I can't seem to access that if I'm using a shader that uses a fragmentShader

Comment: @K2xL Feel free to explore the source code: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/b9f5fe663bda7c50ae8de1e8c83186776ff17733/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderChunk/color_vertex.glsl.js#L20 If you want instanced color in fragment shader, add a varying  and pass the color into fragment shader. Or add another instanced buffer attribute with colors. Creativity is up to you :)

Comment: @prisoner849 Thanks - but I'm still a bit unclear with that code. So is this saying that `vColor` is something automatically available? When I use it everything is still black.

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused with the ask. So previously you used the setColorAt method to pass a color to your instanced mesh? If I am reading this right then the easiest way to get that same color passed to your fragment shader is to just pass the value as a uniform to the shader. You can pass uniform values from javascript to ShaderMaterial and use those values in your shader.

https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Uniform

hope this helps clear things up a bit

Comment: Thanks, but if it is a uniform then all of the instance meshes will be the same color correct?